# The Framework of a Riddle

Tags: word, english, language

> I am a single word.
>
> one of me is spelled the same as many of me
>
> but many of me is said differently than one of me.

Comment: This is getting a lot of valid answers, you may want to make your puzzle a little more specific.

Comment: @paolo got it.  I was rather specific (or at least I thought I was).  The title of this question was a hint.  framework = chassis.

Comment: @downvoter - reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same idea as Dan Russell. My suggestion is:

> Chassis. There is probably several other words of French origin that end in an 's' that aren't pronounced in the singular and that don't change in the plural.

EDIT: That was a lucky guess on my part! I didn't even notice it fitted the title.

Answer (score 7):

The word you're looking for may be

> [Corps](http://dictionary.com/browse/corps)

The singular version is pronounced

> Core

While the plural version is pronounced

> Cores

Comment: support your answer with this :http://www.dictionary.com/browse/corps

Comment: @Sid Thanks for the link, I'm trying to, but I can't figure out how to format it prettily, every time it comes close it comes across as a broken image.

Comment: @Sconibulus Just needed a space after your spoiler tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty dubious, but

> one possible plural of "status" is "status" but with the "u" pronounced long rather than short -- it's from a Latin noun of the fourth declension.

It's dubious because

> most people most of the time just say "statuses".

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be

> a

I am a single word.

> It is

one of me is spelled the same as many of me

> a in French means at

but many of me is said differently than one of me.

> Pronounced differently

Answer (score 1):

> Fracas? (S silent in singular, sounded in plural)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25178)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil This absolutely does provide an answer to the question.  It may not be correct, but it's not a critique/clarification/comment!